# How can I use Index Match to generate a new list without blanks in between?

Tags: excel, index-match

I am trying to generate a seperate filtered table using Index Match in Excel. The idea is to allow users to filter using two dependent dropdown lists. I have 10 columns in total, but the dropdown lists is just using two columns to filter dependently.

So in the new table, the user would be able to see the filtered data. I am using Index Match to generate this new table.

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$K2,MATCH(1,($C2:$C$12=$T$2)*($D2:$D$12=$T$3),0),COLUMNS($A$19:A19)),"")

The generated table gives blank cells in between. How can I have the lists consolidate the data with no blanks in between rows?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAA | AAAAAA |
| BLANK | BLANK |
| BBBBBB | BBBBBB |

Trying to generate a new filtered table without blanks in between rows.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAA | AAAAAA |
| BBBBBB | BBBBBB |

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide a sample of your *source* data (at the best using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) - it is easier to help you. Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: I have Office 365. So I have two tables (master data) and then this new filtered table. Basically, the Excel is to filter data based on Master table using dependent dropdowns. This code works as intended but it is generating blanks in between rows. Which is something we do want. We want the data consolidated as a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Office 365 or above, you can use the following filter formula for the index/match initial result, to get rid of the blank:

```
=filter(A:B,A:A＜＞””)
```

Comment: Do I wrap this around the Index?

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried using this, this is solved now.